# Capybara changes my action_mailer.default_url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, capybara

I ran into a problem, I'm using ruby on rails with devise and want to test the flow of my application with capybara.

When i click links in my e-mails

```
current_email.click_link 'text'
```

it' gives an protocol error, debugging this it seems capybara changes the host that devise uses to make the e-mail.

So i wrote this test:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara-webkit'
require 'capybara/email/rspec'
require 'headless'

describe 'capybara and devise are broken', type: :request do
  it 'action_mailer default url should change when visiting a page' do  
    initialValue = X::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]

    visit "/"

    initialValue.should_not equal X::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]
  end

  it 'action_mailer default url should change when clicking a link' do  
    initialValue = X::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]
    visit "/"
    X::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] = initialValue

    click_link "Can't access?"

    initialValue.should_not equal X::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]
  end

  it 'action_mailer default url should change when clicking a button' do
    initialValue = X::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]
    visit "/"
    X::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] = initialValue

    click_button "Sign in"

    initialValue.should_not equal X::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]
  end

end
```

All these tests succeed and i can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

It's my third week with RoR, so maybe it's something obvious i'm missing?

Gem versions:
gem 'rails', '3.2.7'
gem 'capybara', require: false
gem 'capybara-webkit', '= 0.10.1', require: false
gem 'capybara-screenshot'
gem 'capybara-email'
gem 'devise', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 1.0.0'

Comment: Could it be that the rails environment is set again when capybara  does a click and ror processes that call?

Comment: The code to load in the rails environment came from here: http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/ .

Comment: What about explicitly setting the host in `test.rb`?

Comment: X::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] is already explicetly set in test.rb.